# iPhone restarts randomly

Tags: iphone, ios, restart

I have iPhone 5s 16gb ios 10.2.1 still under warrenty.
I'm facing some random restarts from past few weeks. I went to apple service center, where they kept my phone for few days but didn't face any restart problem, but i faced the same problem the same i got my phone back.
I talked to apple support and they said either i have to replicate the restart problem in front of them as my device is not creating any kind of crash log report or I have to make a video of my device while it randomly restarts.
Both of the tasks seems impossible as niether I'm able to make a video as its happens randomly and in fractions of second nor I'm able to replicate the issue, because if I could have, I would have done it already.
Now Im stuck with my iphone and apple support is not ready to help me.
Im writing here with my best hopes.
Thanks in advance if you can help me in any way.
How it restarts: Black screen suddenly with red thin line over it > black screen without light(energy)>apple logo screen
but from last few times its restarting 3 times in a row(restarts when on apple logo screen).
how it restarts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnrDCshkZiQ